# Which is the most expensive beer as of now?

Tags: history

As of the time this question being asked, which is the most expensive beer in the world?

Is it available now?

Is/was it available for purchase for general public?

What is/was its price?

Comment: I have a can of Tennents that I'm selling for  €1,000,000.

Answer (score 3):

as mentioned above but with more details: the most expensive beer is a 12 liter bottle of Vieille Bon Secours which was stocked in a London restaurant for over 10 years. So it's the age and uniqueness of this one bottle that make it worth around 700£ / 832€.

Answer (score 2):

Vielle Bon Secours ale I think.  It's a Belgian beer brewed by Caulier.  I saw the bottle in London 6 years ago, and it'll cost you around US$1,165.

Answer (score 2):

[Brewdog The End of Hisory](http://www.brewdog.com/blog-article/341) were only produced in a [12 bottle limited edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BrewDog#Beers) with a stuffed squirrel around the bottle costing [£500](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-scotland-north-east-orkney-shetland-10725024) per bottle. Unfortunately, they're all sold out.